# Pandas: generate timeseries datetime features

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF that has `date` as Datetime, ranging from Jan 2013 to Dec 2015. I want to create a time series feature, indicating that each month has a `date_block_num`, increases by one every month.

For example, Jan 2013 is `0`, Feb 2013 is `1`,..., Dec 2013 is `11`, Jan 2014 is `12`, Feb 2014 is `13` and so on.

I can use a simple `iterrows()` to do this, but I wonder if there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data has all the months, you can use `factorize`:

```
DF['date'].dt.to_period('M').sort_values().factorize()
```

Or, you can try some math:

```
years = DF['date'].dt.year
months = DF['date'].dt.month

DF['date_block'] = (years*12 + months) - 2013*12
```

Comment: `DF['date'].dt.to_period('M').sort_values().factorize()[0]` ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this and can solve your problem in one line as suggested by @Quang Hoang

```
df['time_series_feature'] = df['date'].dt.to_period('M').sort_values().factorize()[0].tolist()
```